# Change Linux output to csv

Tags: bash, csv, tr

I need to gather some bash output, preferably in a neat table. The output i receive looks like:

```
Name 1 {
   value 1.1
   value 1.2
   value 1.3
}
Name 2 {
   value 2.1
   value 2.2
   value 2.3
}
...
Name n {
   value n.1
   value n.2
   value n.3
}
```

and so on - the amount of data of course varies from output to output.

I need it to convert it to look like this:

```
Name 1   value 1.1   value 1.2   value 1.3
Name 2   value 2.1   value 2.2   value 2.3
...
Name n   value n.1   value n.2   value n.3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, but your output isn't CSV, and not even TSV (at least in your input sample data there are no tabs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "\n" | tr -s "}" "\n" | tr -d "{"
```

Comment: Nice idea. It could be further simplified: `tr -d "\n{" < file.txt | tr "}" "\n"`

Comment: That helps a lot - but I do have an additional question:
How can you modify it to add a comma or a semicolon in between every piece of data. That would help to import it  to excel based on a separator>